# member initializer does not name a non-static data member or base class

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I'm having a hard time finding hits on google for this.

```
struct a {
    float m_x;
    float m_z;
public:
    a(float x): m_x(x) {}
};

class b : public a {
    b(float z): m_z(z) {}
};
```

On clang 3.2:

```
error: member initializer 'm_z' does not name a non-static data member or base class
    b(float z): m_z(z) {}
```

Comment: Why? I haven't made an "evil inheritance diamond" yet.  @AndreyT the accepted answer in that question says to make a base ctor. I have one... oh. I guess i need to be calling the base class ctor, not the member ctor. ok.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Even if it is a virtual base, it still won't let you initialize *indirect* members. Virtual inheritance might require initialization of indirect *bases*, but not members.

Comment: @Steven Lu: The accepted answer says that `a::m_z` can only be initialized from `a`'s constructor initializer list. It cannot be mentioned in `b`'s constructor initializer list (as in your code). The language does not allow that. That's the point. I.e. you have to add another parameter to `a`'s constructor specificallly for `m_z` (as you did for `m_x`) and pass the initial value from `b` through that constructor. BTW, in your code above you have to refer to `a`'s constructor from `b`'s constructor. Otherwise, it won't compile, since you have no default constructor in `a`.

Comment: Got it, thanks.  It's fine if this question is closed, but I think it should stay searchable so that clang users with this error can quickly track down the solution.

Comment: @AndreyT So correct sir, I was momentarily distracted by a combination of sleep deprivation and the simultaneous arrival of a pizza. Eh. dropping comment.

Answer (score 70):

No you cannot initialize base class members from initializer list directly. This is because order of initialization proceeds in this way

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 12.6.2/10

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
> following order:

— First, and only for the constructor of the most

> derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
> they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
> acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
> appearance of the base classes in the derived class
> base-specifier-list.

— **Then, direct base classes are initialized** in

> declaration order as they appear in the base-specifier-list
> (regardless of the order of the mem-initializers).

— **Then, non-static

> data members are initialized** in the order they were declared in the
> class definition (again regardless of the order of the
> mem-initializers).

— **Finally, the compound-statement of the

> constructor body is executed**.
>
> [ Note: The declaration order is mandated to ensure that base and
> member subobjects are destroyed in the reverse order of
> initialization. — end note ]

So you can specify a constructor in a base class (it can be protected) and use that one in initialization list of derived class ([should be preferred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23493639/1141471)) or you can *assign* to a base class member in derived class ctor body (different behaviour, different effect and also less efficient - you are assigning to default initialized (already has value) member).

In the former case you might write it this way:

```
struct A {
    float m_x;
    float m_z;
    A(){}
protected:
    A(float x, float z): m_x(x), m_z(z) {}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B(float x, float z) : A(x, z) {}
    // alternatively
    // B(float x, float z) {
    //     m_x = x;
    //     m_z = z;
    // }
};

int main(){
    B b(1.0f, 2.0f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code example is wrong: OP meant to do `m_z = z`, not `m_x = z` and of course, the `A(z)` would be wrong in that case (and it also means `m_z` is not initialized in an A object and `m_x` not initialized in a B object).