# Constructor two dots

Tags: c++, constructor

```
class X {
  public:
    X(int ii = 0) : i(ii) { 
     j = i; // j can't be accessed by non-static methods
}
```

What does `: i(ii)`  mean? More exactly, the two dots.

Comment: `i` will be initialized with `ii`. What that means depends on  `i`

Comment: two dots are called colon

Comment: And it can be used only in constructors?

Comment: You need to get yourself a book on the basics of C++. You can easily find this information in many many tutorials online as well.

Comment: If I knew it was called colon, maybe.

Comment: They are known as `Initialization Lists`. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/init-lists.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493639/1141471

Comment: used for Initialization of member variables.

Comment: You can read through [learncpp.com](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/b-4-initializer-lists-and-uniform-initialization/). Read the other articles too.