# How to initialise const member variable of superclass in constructor of subclass in C++?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, list-initialization

I have the following situation, I declared a `const` member of a *superclass* and now I want to initialize it within the the constructor of one of its *subclasses* using a *list initializer*.

```
struct Shape {
public:
    const Rect boundingRect; // the rect in which the shape is contained
};

struct Stain : Shape
{
public:
    Stain(Rect boundingRect_) : boundingRect(boundingRect_) {}
};
```

I am not sure if this is even possible, if I take the straightforward approach shown above, the compiler complains with the following message:

```
member initializer 'boundingRect' does not name a non-static data member or base class
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479295/member-initializer-does-not-name-a-non-static-data-member-or-base-class) explains why it's not possible to initialize member variables of a superclass in *list initiliazers* of a *subclass's* constructor. I am wondering what the best practice might be for that situation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to add a constructor for `struct Shape` and call it from your sub-class. Like so:

```
struct Shape {
public:
    const Rect boundingRect; // the rect in which the shape is contained

    Shape( Rect rect ) : boundingRecT( rect ) {}
};

struct Stain : Shape
{
public:
    Stain(Rect boundingRect_) : Shape (boundingRect_) {}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only initialize a class's member variables and base classes here (not the base class's members).

The solution is to give `Shape` a constructor which accepts the initializer, e.g.:

```
Shape(Rect rect): boundingRect(rect) {}
```

and `Stain` invokes it like this:

```
Stain(Rect boundingRect_): Shape(boundingRect_) {}
```

If you don't want the general public using this constructor you can make it `protected:`.