# member initializer 'SuperClass' does not name a non-static data member or base class

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a problem with some of my constructors. Both subclasses need to get the same classes (no super class), that is why these classes should be initialized in the super class:

```
template<typename T, typename S>   
class SuperClass {
protected:
    OtherClass <T> const& _class1;
    OtherOtherClass <T> const& _class2;

    SuperClass() {

    }

    SuperClass(OtherClass<T> const& class1, OtherOtherClass<T> const& class2)
        : _class1(class1), _class2(class2)
    {
            // Alternative I tried:
            // this->_class1 = class1;
            // this->_class2 = class2;
    }
```

I tried to use it through:

```
    template<typename T, typename S> 
    class SubClass1 : public SuperClass<T, S> {
    private:
        someFunc() {
            return this->_class1.getSomething(); // as an example
        }

    public:
        SubClass1(OtherClass<T> const& class1,
                OtherOtherClass<T> const& class2)
                : SuperClass(class1, class2)
            {
                // some definitions
            }

     }
```

After that this error shows up:

> member initializer
>         'SuperClass' does not name a non-static data member or base
>         class

I found some people with similar problems, but it did not lead me to the solution. For example: [member initializer does not name a non-static data member or base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18479295/member-initializer-does-not-name-a-non-static-data-member-or-base-class)
I did not see many difference there and tried to add an empty constructor like he did.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Can you please show the definition of the class `SubClass1`?

Comment: Should it read SuperClass<T,S>(...)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error says it all:

> member initializer '`SuperClass`' does not name a non-static data member or base class

`SuperClass` is not a class. It's a class *template*. As such, it's not the base class of your type. The base class is a specific instantiation of the class template: `SuperClass<T,S>`. That's what you need:

```
    SubClass1(OtherClass<T> const& class1,
            OtherOtherClass<T> const& class2)
    : SuperClass<T,S>(class1, class2)
    //          ^^^^^
```

Comment: For the record, VC++ and Intel's compilers can figure out `<T, S>` from base class spec (`: public SuperClass<T, S>`), which seems more intuitive to me. GCC and Clang can't do that. Don't know which behaviour is more standard-compliant.